# How to use ADO.NET GetSchema() to get only user-defined stored procedures?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

`Connection.GetSchema["Procedures"]` returns all stored procedures including **system** ones. How can I restrict it to only return **user defined** stored procedures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add **restrictions** to the `GetSchema` method.

```
string[] restrictions = new string[] { null, null, null, "P" };
var x = connection.GetSchema("Procedures", restrictions);
```

According to [MSDN GetSchema reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716722(v=vs.110).aspx). If you look in the **Procedures** section, the **4th parameter** for Procedure is `Type`.

I don't have any code open, so I'm not 100% sure the above will do the trick, but it should certainly get you on the right track.

Comment: How did you arrive at the argument "P" - ie why not "PROCEDURE"?

Comment: "P" is used because that's the value for Stored Procedures in `type` column  of `sys.objects` table. See here for all types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql

Comment: Right, well I have several unit tests here to prove that adding the array filter, using the word "PROCEDURE" as the the 4th element in the array, filters out "functions" and only lists "stored procs" - which is what I was trying to do (ie with no filter array, I get functions as well using just connection.GetSchema("Procedures")

Answer (score 0):

The first line should read:

```
string[] restrictions = new string[] { null, null, null, "PROCEDURE" };
```